# Scripts not getting loaded in the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jsoneditor

I checked the similar post [How to set Content Security Policy in Chrome Extension Manifest.json in order for Firebase to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889154/how-to-set-content-security-policy-in-chrome-extension-manifest-json-in-order-fo). I got the issue is related to CSP but however whats the policy I need to set is what I didn't get unfortunately.

I built a chrome extension which uses [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) and that dependency creates this issue. When running the extension I am getting the following exception

> Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,....' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

and

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'data:application/javascript;base64,......' failed to load.
>       at blob:chrome-extension://nlgocoglacibgkjnhaahkmepblhmelcp/765c13cb-44d4-480c-a6b1-29527766ae5e:1:1

In the SO question mentioned above urls like

`https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com;` are included in `content_security_policy`.

In my example the script is not loaded from outside domain. How to set the right `content_security_policy` in this case?

Comment: I guess you need to allow `data:` for `worker-src` in CSP.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried with this `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; worker-src 'self' data: blob:; object-src 'self'"`

still same error.

Comment: Finally got it working with `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' data: blob:; worker-src 'self' data: blob:; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: If you got it to work and no longer need help, you should probably post your own solution as an answer and close the question.

Comment: @PetrSrníček posted my solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is the addition of `script-src-elem 'self' data: blob:;` in the `content_security_policy` in the `manifest.json` file.

Mine looks like the following,

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' data: blob:; worker-src 'self' data: blob:; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: where will be this manisfest.json file for Google Chrome in linux mint.